# Auto-Layout Ignoring the Status Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using 'Proportional Height to Superview' to size two views on top each other (the first is 75%, the other is 25%). My problem is the Superview's height ignores the status bar (i.e. still 667 points for iPhone 6s instead of 647).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some check box I need to tick or code I need to write? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like your superview is going under the status bar. Check if the top of your superview's top is set to match to the top layout guide or the top of its superview.

The top layout guide will be below the status bar, which would explain why that view's height excludes the status bar area.

Comment: Using a view controller’s `topLayoutGuide` is the correct approach.

Comment: I do use 'Top Space to: Top Layout Guide'. The superview does go under the status bar, but instead of shrinking, it goes down 20 points, so the elements at the very bottom get cut off. That's why this is very puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

in your controller, is subtracted automatically size the status bar, and all components are re-adjusted

Comment: I do need the status bar to be visible, so I can't use that, unfortunately. Also, there will be instances that one of my ViewControllers will be embedded in a NavigationController, but the view's height does not adjust, so all the elements are moved down instead of shrunk.